# using securestring for a sql connection

Tags: c#, .net, securestring

I want to use a SecureString to hold a connection string for a database. But as soon as I set the SqlConnection object's ConnectionString property to the value of the securestring surely it will become visible to any other application that is able to read my application's memory?

I have made the following assumptions: 
a) I am not able to instantiate a SqlConnection object outside of managed memory 
b) any string within managed memory can be read by an application such as [Hawkeye](http://www.acorns.com.au/Projects/Hawkeye/)

Comment: Apparently Hawkeye 1.2.0 can show SecureStrings... So, what is your question?

Comment: Oh - so what's the point in securestrings then?

Comment: Persist Security Info  property of the connection string may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your absolutely right the SecureString does not provide you with any benefit when you need to pass the string to a managed API, such as setting a ConnectionString.

It's really designed for secure communication with secure non-managed APIs.

Microsoft could theoretically consider enhancing SqlConnection object to support a secure ConnectionString, but I think they're unlikely to do so because:

- SecureString is really only useful in a client app, where e.g. a password is built character by character from user input, without ever having the whole password in a managed string.
- In such an environment, it's more common to be using Windows authentication for connections to SQL Server.
- On a server there are other ways to protect the SQL Server credentials, starting by limiting access to the server to authorized administrators.

---

**2012**

Microsoft *did* enhance **[SqlConection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)** object to support a secure **ConnectionString** by passing a **[SqlCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcredential(v=vs.110).aspx)** to the new  **[SqlConnection.Credential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.credential(v=vs.110).aspx)** property:

```
SecureString pwd = AzureVault.GetSecretStringSecure("ProcessPassword");
SqlCredential = new SqlCredential("Richard", pwd)
connection.Credential = cred;
```

Unfortunately no other **[DbConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)** descendant  *(e.g., OdbcConnection, OleDbConnection, OracleConnection, EntityConnection, DB2Connection)* supports it.

Comment: .NET 4.5 will allow a password to be passed as a SecureString when using SQL Server Authentication:  [What's New in ADO.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6y04yf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It is my opinion that SecureString is meant for all type of communication of secrets in a secured way and not restricted to non-managed APIs. Per Lee SecureString are supported with .NET 4.5. I am personally working in enterprise support engineering environments where the lowest level support may have access to some data in SQL yet are not granted the knowledge what is the SQL user's password. Instead this secret is encrypted before hand with a certificate and the program is granted use of the certificate but not the user.

Comment: @DavidBurg - I don't understand your point.  SqlConnection.ConnectionString still doesn't use SecureString in .NET 4.5.  If you can avoid the need for a password, then clearly this is a better solution, but this isn't always the case.  And a program that uses a certificate for authentication doesn't need SecureString.

Comment: @Joe - The point is you no longer need a SqlConnection.ConnectionString containing the user credentials with password, instead you use SqlCredential object to pass the credentials in which the password is used but as a SecureString. Yes a certificate is another entirely different approach. SqlCredential is a smaller footprint change as you may continue to use a password.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can and yes you should use SecureString to avoid letting password linger in the clear in memory and open up to attacks. Rather than using a sql connection string, you need to use the new SqlCredential class which Password property is a SecureString. Please refer to the below articles for help.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcredential.password(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/408901/Storing-your-connection-string-password-in-SecureS

Answer (score 0):

Why is the connection string an issue? Wouldn't the password be what you want to protect (unless you're putting the password in the connection string which is optional for all drivers that I've seen). That being said, the password will usually have to be "in the clear" in memory at some point (unless the driver has some api that allows encrypted passwords or something, but that probably wouldn't actually help much anyway).

Usually this is not a problem because the process is in a secure environment, like on a web server, or running as a system admin type of account (so normal users cannot access the process memory), or usually both. If this is on a client's machine running in userland you must assume that the process is compromised anyway and this wouldn't help. Once you secure the process you don't have to worry about things like this.

Comment: End users are not the only threat. Third party APIs may become one too. I agree though that if you are writing an app and know / trust every single of its dependencies, then it's probably not that big a deal. But in some companies, you do not have that luxury.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a SecureString value to SQLConnection.ConnectionString will bypass the security, making it useless.

A SecureString is meant to fix these normal string issues, [ref](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/05/27/143254.aspx):

- not pinned, garbage collector can move it around, leaving copies in memory
- not encrypted
- If your process gets swapped out to disk, the string will be sitting in your swap file
- not mutable, modifying it will keep the old version and the new version both in memory
- no way to clear it out when you're done using it

IMHO the SecureString type is a patch for a shoddy security implementation, and currently SecureString hasn't been implemented all across the framework, so it's benefits can't be used fully.

I have the same problem, I'm opting for RSA encryption storing sensitive info in memory.

Another solution is hosting your data access layer via a service on the database server, and the service runs under the local system account, that connects to the database and serves the data, while the local user wont have access to the service config.

Comment: With new version of .NET, SecureString implementation is more holistic making the original response a bit obsolete.

Answer (score -3):

If you are that concerned about security I suggest you should enable SSL in SQL server and communicate with it using SSL.

Comment: Wouldn't the connection password still have to be in memory at some point though?

Comment: @JonB @Shamika yeah, I think it would too

Comment: I don't see what using SSL has to do with the question.

Comment: This is a bit orthogonal to the original question.